# Custom endpoint in Wordpress REST API is forbidden but I am logged in

Tags: wordpress, rest, endpoint

Created a custom endpoint with the Wordpress REST API and have set the `permission_callback` to `edit_posts`. The endpoint is called when the user clicks on menu item I added in the dashboard. It basically is a `GET` request for exporting a database table.

However, the request throws a `rest_forbidden` error (401).

My code looks like this:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('foobar', '/get_calculator_results', array(
        'methods'             => 'GET',
        'callback'            => 'get_calculator_results',
        'permission_callback' => function () {
            return current_user_can('edit_posts');
        }
    ));
});

add_action("admin_menu", "add_export_results_menu_item");
function add_export_results_menu_item()
{
    $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on') ? "https://" : "http://";
    $link     = $protocol . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/wp-json/foobar/get_calculator_results";
    add_menu_page("Export results", "Export results", "edit_posts", $link, "", "", 2);
}
```

Am I applying the `permission_callback` the wrong way?

Comment: You might not even need a ```permission_callback```! Usually you get ```401``` because you didn't pass the ```nonce```. Can you edit your question and add your javascript rest api call snippet? There is almost always a bug in there and it's almost always the nonce!

Comment: @Ruvee Maybe I don't understand your question, but the code in my original post is all there is. I do not have any JavaScript logic.

Comment: If you're not using javascript, then how do you make a ```GET``` request to your custom endpoint?

Comment: @Ruvee All I did was add a additional menu item in the dashboard of the CMS and set the link of that menu item to my custom created endpoint, for example https://example.com/wp-json/foobar/get_calculator_results. Visiting that link will trigger the function I have set within the endpoint that does some logic. All of this is written in my `functions.php` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the link did not contain a `_wpnonce`. My code now looks like this and the link is no longer forbidden for authorized users:

```
add_action("admin_menu", "add_export_results_menu_item");
function add_export_results_menu_item()
{
    $protocol  = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on') ? "https://" : "http://";
    $link      = $protocol . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/wp-json/foobar/get_calculator_results";
    $nonce     = wp_create_nonce('wp_rest');
    $nonceLink = $link . '?_wpnonce=' . $nonce;
    add_menu_page("Export results", "Export results", "edit_posts", $nonceLink, "", "", 2);
}
```

Comment: Wow, almost 2 hours of Googling/debugging, all because I wasn't appending the wp_create_nonce call to my URL. WordPress' documentation truly is the worst. Nowhere on the register_rest_route API page did it mention wp_create_nonce. Thanks for this.